# put a Prolog goal as input in the first argument position and returns the number of times this goal succeeds in the second argument position

Tags: count, prolog, meta-predicate

As the title says I want to write a program that does this.

an example would be:

```
?- count(member(X,[1,2,3]), N). 

N = 3 

Yes
```

But not only for the build in member, but also for some operators like:

```
?- count(17 =:= 12 + 5, N). 

N = 1 

Yes
```

Can someone help me get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`?- findall(., Goal, Ls), length(Ls, L).`

Example:

```
?- findall(., member(X,[1,2,3]), Ls), length(Ls, L).
L = 3,
... .
```

Comment: I again recommend you think in terms of *relations* when programming in Prolog. This question is probably related to you previous counter question, and I recommend you think this through more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) has been implemented to provide solutions for your problem, and much more...

```
?- aggregate(count, X^member(X,[1,2,3]), N).
N = 3.

?- aggregate(count, 17 =:= 12 + 5, N).
N = 1.
```